# Spring Data JPA with SQL Server giving error: Invalid object name 'Table_Name'

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to save a list of object in a `sql-server` database in my `Spring Boot` application but getting exception when I call the `save` method.

```
2018-11-26 11:50:41.896  WARN 22082 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : SQL Error: 208, SQLState: S0002
2018-11-26 11:50:41.897 ERROR 22082 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper             : Invalid object name 'ticket'.
```

Below is the configuration am using:

```
#SQL Server configurations
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://my.server.ip.address;databaseName=UH
spring.datasource.username=Test
spring.datasource.password=Test@123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

And the `Model` looks like:

```
@Entity(name = "Ticket")
public class Ticket {

    public Ticket() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "ticket_id", nullable = false, length=200)
    private long ticket_id;

    @Column(name = "topic", nullable = false, length=200)
    private String topic;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Tag> tag;

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, length=200)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "brand", nullable = false, length=200)
    private long brand;

    @Column(name = "ticket_group", nullable = false, length=200)
    private long ticket_group;

    @Column(name = "priority", nullable = false, length=200)
    private String priority;

    @Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length=200)
    private String status;


    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, length=200)
    private String created_date;

    @Column(name = "created_time", nullable = false, length=200)
    private String created_time;

    @Column(name = "channel", nullable = false, length=200)
    private String channel;

    // Getters & Setters....

}
```

I have created the `Repository` class:

```
@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Long> {

}
```

and finally, the controller:

```
@RestController
public class TicketController {


  @Autowired
  TicketRepository ticketRepository;

  @GetMapping("/tickets")
  public void saveTicketData() {

      List<Ticket> tickets = null;
      try {
            tickets = getAllTickets();  //some utility method
            ticketRepository.save(tickets);  // here exception occurs
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
}
```

Not sure what is wrong here. Is there a different way to save list of objects in SQL server than in MySQl? This works great with MySQL or if I switch to Mongo.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you also show your utility method.

Comment: erm, can screenshot your database schema/table? just curious that whether you put the name as "db"...

Comment: edited the db name. That's exactly what I have created in SQl server

Comment: @PoojaAggarwal: Utility method is nothing but parses some JSON and created Ticket object, populates ticket fields and save it the a set and returns.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I missed the following setting:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

It was reformatting the Table name for some reason.

Comment: hello savior. Not sure why this is not mentioned anywhere in the docs

Answer (score 1):

Include one more annotation `@Table(name = "Ticket")` in Entity Class.

`@Table(name = "Ticket")
@Entity(name = "Ticket")
public class Ticket {.....`

Comment: What is the table name in db? Depending upon OS the SQL Server table names may be case sensitive. So, please  check the table name is small case `ticket` or `Ticket`. It must be `ticket`.

Comment: It is hosted on windows. table name is `ticket`

Answer (score 1):

Sqlserver is case sensitive so if the table name is TICKET it does not recognize "i" char in Ticket. 
Can you check if the table name is TICKET or ticket. if it is TICKET then try this annotation.

```
@Table(name = "TICKET")
@Entity(name = "TICKET")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case table is not created with JPA. We are created table externally and then all other operation like insert select was done. So , I am facing this issue because of table's absense